# VB.Net shell output sometimes not returning

Tags: vb.net, shell, streamreader

for 99% of all my Shell commands this code works fine, but for just one command I don't get the returned text, which is normally visible in the Shell window. Here is the code I use to execute commands and read back the results:

```js
Function RunCommandCom(command As String, arguments As String) As String()

Dim p As Process = New Process()
Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
Dim output As String

pi.Arguments = " " + "/c" + " " + command + " " + arguments
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
pi.RedirectStandardOutput = True 'pi.CreateNoWindow = True
pi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
pi.UseShellExecute = False
p.StartInfo = pi
p.Start()
output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
p.WaitForExit()
p.Close()

If output Is ""
Then
Return Nothing
Else
Return output.Replace(Chr(13), "").Split(Chr(10))
End If


End Function
```

The command making Problems is executed fine. It shall create a entry in a database, which defintly is existing after calling my funciton. Executing the command directly in a Shell generates the same entry and I can see the returned text.

Does anyone has an idea why the streamreader does not read/contain anything for exactly this one special command?

Comment: I identified another command causing the same Problem. Both are somehow "create" commands and may take longer than other commands. Migth that be the reason for the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that both of those programs actually write to stdout"?  Do both of them always fail to return anything?

Comment: I think so. I see the information I wanna read back in my Shell window when executing the command manually. The command I type in, is exactly the same as my code sends to cmd.exe. And both do the same, as I can see the same data later on in my database.
Is it possible, that the text I see in my Shell window is not part of the stoudt stream my programm can read?

For both commands I always get a empty string when reading the stoudt stream.
For all other commands the stoudt stream contains what I would normally see in my Shell window.

Comment: One other possible issue.  You're reading from the output stream immediately after you start the process.  You may wish to read the stream just after the process exits but before you close the Process instance.  Perhaps you are missing some data.

Answer (score 0):

Arg. I found the problem. These two commands send their output to the StandardError stream. I don't know why, as no error occured.